# Error 'Program.Number' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable

Tags: c#

Error 'Program.Number' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable

i keep geting the above error when i try to run this program what am i doing wrong

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum Number{ standard = 1, express = 2, same = 3};

    const int A = 1, B = 2;
    const int Y = 3, N = 4;

    static void Main()
     {

        double cost, LB;
        int numValues, Number_of_items ;

         Console.WriteLine("please enter the type of shiping you want");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 1:standard shipping.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 2:express shipping.");
        Console.WriteLine("Enter 3:same day shipping.");


        switch ((Number))
        { 
            case Numbers.standard:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing standerd shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                {      if (A==A)
                {
                    Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                    Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 3 * Number_of_items;

                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (y or n)");
                    if (Y==Y)
                    {
                        cost = cost + 2.50;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                    }
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);


                }
                else 
                Console.Write("please enter the weiht in pounds");
               LB =  double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                cost = 1.45 * LB;
                Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (y or n)");
        }
                if (Y==Y)
                {
                    cost = cost + 2.50;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                }
                else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);

                break;


                case Numbers.express:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing Express Shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");

                    {       if (A==A)
                        Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                        Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                        cost = 4 * Number_of_items;
                        {
                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (y or n)");
                    if (Y==Y)
                    {
                        cost = cost + 5.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                    }
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);


                    }
                     if(B==B) 

                Console.Write("please enter the weiht in pounds");
               LB =  double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                cost = 2.50 * LB;
                Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (y or n)");
                    }
                if (Y==Y)
                {
                    cost = cost + 5.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                }
                else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);
            break;





                case Numbers.same:
                Console.WriteLine("thankyou for chooseing Same Day Shipping");
                Console.WriteLine("please choose a catagory");
                Console.Write("Type A or B to make your selection");
                if (A == A)
                    Console.Write("please enter the number of items");
                    Number_of_items = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    cost = 5.50 * Number_of_items;

                    Console.Write("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (y or n)");
                    if (Y==Y)
                    {
                        cost = cost + 8.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                    }
                    else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);



                if (B==B)

                Console.Write("please enter the weiht in pounds");
               LB =  double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                cost = 3.00 * LB;
                Console.WriteLine("is this shipment going to alaska or Hawaii? (y or n)");

                if (Y==Y)
                {
                    cost = cost + 8.00;

                        Console.WriteLine("Total cost is {0}." , cost);
                }
                else 
                        Console.WriteLine("total cost is {0}." , cost);

                break;
        }


        numValues = 1; 

















   Console.ReadLine();

    }//End Main()
}//End class Program
```

Comment: well, the compiler is (as is often the case) correct... where exactly do you *think* you are obtaining a value that you are testing in the `switch` ?

Comment: enum Number{ standard = 1, express = 2, same = 3}; is where i thought i got it but this is my first time using switches and am a little lost

Comment: all that line does is define an `enum` - which is just some convenient names for integers; it doesn't obtain a *value* for anything

Comment: allright so where do i go from here then i would like them to be able to enter the numbers 1-3 and go to that case

Comment: Look at @minitech answer for reading input from the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are switching on the type `Number`, must use an instance of `Number`.
for example:

```
switch ((Number)myNumber)
```

Comment: ok but where do i put myNumber in my code like as a const or a int ?

Comment: You must assign variable `myNumber` a value. If it is of type `Number` you dont have to cast it in the switch.

Comment: ok i assigned it a value but now im stuck with case 1 (the value i assinged ) how do i make it so it will ask the user for that value with the switch

Comment: `var myNumber = (Number)int.Parse(Console.ReadLine())`

Comment: ok i fixed this part of the code thankyou for the quick responses

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
switch((Number))
```

I think you were about to cast something to `Number` but forgot to. So I'll assume you meant:

```
int input;

while(!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), ref input) || input < 1 || input > 3) {
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter a valid option!");
}

switch((Number)input)
```